# Firebase Firestore with REST (PHP)

Tags: php, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using Firebase Firestore for one of my mobile application. I need to read something from some external site and update/overwrite one Firestore field every Monday at certain time. Right now I am doing it manually. I want to automate this process.

I have a PHP application with Cpanel. I want to have a CRON job that will update this field every Monday. I am planning to use REST calls to Firestore in order to update the field but not able to do the Authentication part...

I have also created the service account for my application and downloaded the project-name-xxxx.json file with private key. I also have the API-KEY. But not knowing how to use both of these in order to authenticate and communicate. I am trying Postman for now but no luck.

Can some one tells me how can I authenticate with REST API suing the API-KEY and json file I have.

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All right, so there are two ways of doing this.

1. Program a cloud function, and within it set the field you want, and call it from a client SDK, with an authenticated user to the system, or
2. On your remote site, install the Node Admin SDK, and use there the service account to connect directly to firestore and update the field.

Comment: A cloud function is better, I think. Easier.

Comment: Thank you for your time. As I need to update only one field every time, I am just passing the value as a request parameter to the http based firebase cloud function and it worked. I am still facing issue with setting up client SDK or node Admin SDK on my php server...

Comment: No prob. Yeah, so for starters I think there's no PHP Admin SDK, so you need to have Node installed and run the code from there, I did this, but I don't have the sample at hand; the client SDK for Web is Javascript to be run on the browser.